# how to setup the Spring Boot Admin Server via war-deployment in a external tomcat?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, war, spring-boot-admin

I'm trying to set up spring-boot-admin via war deployment. for war i'm not able to see the client application in spring boot admin dashboard.

I've tried with spring boot version 2.1.6 and tomcat version 8.5.47 but i'm not able to see the client application in dashboard.

My client application POM

```
<version>1.0.0</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<name>spring-boot-admin-client</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot Admin - Client</description>
```

Dependencies I have used:

```
spring-boot-starter-actuator
spring-boot-admin-starter-client
spring-boot-starter-security
spring-boot-starter-test
spring-boot-starter-web
```

Not getting any error message but client application i'm not able to see it in spring-boot-admin dashboard.

Answer (score -1):

Have u configured `spring.boot.admin.client.instance.service-url` property in client application?

Generally when Spring Boot Client is installed on external tomcat, SBA predicts the actuator endpoints path as `http://server:port/actuator` while the actual path is `http://server:port/context-root/actuator`.

This is where `spring.boot.admin.client.instance.service-url` property comes to the rescue. `spring.boot.admin.client.instance.service-url` should be set as `http://server:port/context-root`

Comment: This could be a comment, than an Answer. Answer is something you give once you clearly understand the scenario.